# How can I make this abstract programing question easier to answer?

Tags: support, questions

A few days ago, I asked this question: [Program that securely accesses another password protected service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813660/program-that-securely-accesses-another-password-protected-service)

In the past, I have had a lot of success posting questions on Stackoverflow.  However, I feel that whenever I ask more abstract "What's the best way to do this?"-type questions, I don't have nearly as much success.

I feel like this category of question has some merit, but I obviously I don't really know what the best practices are for asking such questions and so I'd like to get some feedback so I can post clearer and more attractive questions of this type in the future.

Comment: If you're actually asking,  "What's the best way to do this?" type questions, those are off-topic, because there is no problem to solve.  You haven't thought it through to the point required for people to actually answer the question.  The best way to do something has no right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact of the matter is not that the question has or doesn't have merit. It's more that SO is NOT MADE for opinion based or very broad questions. Asking for a design strategy or something similar is bound to explode with "well this way is better than this way", "I would use tool X because tool Y has this flaw", and similar stuff that is VERY opinion based.

SO isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, with specific questions and answers.

I'm not saying your question is bad, just that is has no place on a pure Q&A site like SO. Try coding forums maybe? or looking up blogs.  Once you have part of your solution, post a question like :

"I was trying to access passworded devices using tool X, and when using this, I encountered the following issue".